# Need help over the methodology of HTML/JS, where to start building a 10x10 multiplication table that should be later on dynamic

Tags: javascript, html, operators, html-table

I've looked at other questions here about these "simple" multiplication tables.
I'm coming with an even more basic question, I need to understand how Javascript works when I write and incorporate it with HTML (that's where I get confused.)

So in the multiplication exercise, I've created a `<div>` box in HTML, so my question is:
Do I create the matrix 10x10 (rows/columns and numbers) in the body of HTML and then use Javascript? Or do I create rows/columns and numbers first in my `script.js` with HTML tags that would run the table dynamically up to 10 for both row and column?

I just started learning Javascript and this is a problem I come across often. How do I build the syntax, what follows what and if I should put HTML in the script or build it in the HTML file with class/id's and such.

Newbie links explaining this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Actually both approach are used in production. HTML is just your markup, it can be static or dynamically created with JS but data is, most of the times, dynamic.

Now,

1. when you are loading your table for the 1st time, say at page load, you can either send static html table from server and then loop through each table rows to fill in the data or you can do the same thing from JS.

*(And yes, it is perfectly normal to put your html in your scripts if you know what you are doing and why you are doing so.)*

2. when you are just updating values in your table say via ajax calls, you will only loop through the table (which is already there from point 1) rows and populate them.

See this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fuv6xq6/) for dynamically creating html table using js

HTML

```
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

JS

```
function buildTable () {
    var htm = '';
    //the row counter loop
    for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        htm += '<tr>';

        //the columns in each row
        for(var j=1; j<=10; j++) {
        htm += '<td> Row=' + i + ' Column=' + j + ' </td>'; 
        }
        htm += '</tr>';
    }

    //add the rows inside the table
    document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = htm;
}

document.onready = buildTable();
```

If you wanted something else to know please mention in comments and I will update my answer accordingly.

Thank you.

*************** **EDIT / EXPLANATION** ********************

My **buildTable** function is same as your **init** function.

Now, your code will not give desired result because in your code you are using 2 for loops separately. You first need to understand the basics of coding and logic and how to use for loops.

My approach is very simple,
take a string variable, `var htm = '';`

Now start adding HTML to it.

The 1st for loop will make the rows`(<tr>)` in table and the 2nd *nested for loop* will create columns `(<td>)` in each row. And it will keep appending to the string variable `htm`

And when all the for loops are done, we will have our `htm` variable with all the HTML that needs to go inside  and

so we put the htm content in the innerHTML of our table, by doing,

```
document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML = htm;
```

Now tell me which part actually you didn't understand?

You seem to be just starting out with coding and logic. You 1st need to practice some basics of HTML and JavaScripts and then these will all come to you very easily.

Comment: Hi @SumanBarick,

Thanks first of all. Actually I haven't learned stuff you put there and if possible, I prefer to show you from what I've learned, but the "for" loops are the same.

This is my HTML:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Luach Hakefel</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
</head>

<body onLoad="init()">

<div class="all_site" id="all_site">
<div class="box" id="box">
<script src="_script/script.js"></script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: And this is my JS:

function init()
{
 var i;
 var j;
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = '<table>';
for (i=1; i<10; i++) 
    {
    document.box.write("<tr>");
 }
  for (j=1; j<10; j++)
    {
    document.box.write("<td>"+ j*i + "</td>");    
    }
document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = '</table>';
}

I know the code is screwed up, since i'm new so I would appreciate a more basic approach and explanation.

Thanks again!